# You're making a difference!

Tags: discussion

Occasionally, we receive some e-mails that really make us proud of doing the job we do here, thanking us for the knowledge this site, along with a few others on the network, has made available. These generally are pretty vague and just thank us for the site in general, though we've recently received one in particular that actually went into a little bit of detail. This is always a very pleasant thing to hear/read, but we cannot overlook who is really responsible for this: **YOU**.

As I mentioned above, the most recent e-mail we received saying "thanks!" went into a bit more detail about the situation in which this site was helpful for the user. The user is a regular browser of this site for a while now, and over this time they've had "the good fortune to read some excellent answers by people who are at the top of their field."

They go on to describe how recently the company they work for was the victim of fraud that run into five-figure amounts, but that thanks to the information learnt on this site (and a few others from the network) they had a clear and immediate notion of what was going on and how to proceed, which allowed them to act quickly and recover the money.

Lastly, they say this is thanks to information and knowledge that they likely wouldn't have had access to without this site, and gave credit to the people who manage, moderate and contribute to this site. Thanks to them, they were able to manage a large scale fraud and essentially save their company from being scammed out of a significant amount of money.

Although these users don't post these "thanks" here — and the user from the e-mail described above in particular didn't wish to post it here for privacy reasons — themselves I think it's important that you know **you're doing a good job and making a difference**. Keep up the good work!

Comment: That gives me the warm fuzzies - it really does. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Can you share any more info - like any specifics on what has helped most, for example?

Comment: +1 to @RoryAlsop. Definitely glad to know our site is appreciated. Any further information you can share about the content of the e-mails, while anonymizing their sources if so requested, would be very nice to have.

Comment: If I'm making the difference, why haven't I received my t-shirt for my nomination in the last election, EH?

Comment: Except that one guy. He's not doing a good job. You know who you are. *GET WITH THE PROGRAM, MAN*

Comment: @JeffAtwood Is this because I was picking on you about ECC this week...?

Comment: I made the information a little less vague — it had been made intentionally vague because the user had privacy concerns, but they then explicitly said I could be more descriptive if I thought it was appropriate. To be clear, the user also mentioned that they hoped I could pass the information to the people who deserve it, hence why I posted this here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop see https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/

Comment: It wasn't me, but I've been reading Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow now for a while.  Until recently, I haven't had the skill to post answers here.  Thanks to all the volunteers, however, I've been able to grow professionally and technically.  For me, it was the frank discussion of possible solutions to problems - I really appreciated seeing multiple ways of doing something and understand why some solutions were better than others.